# Как отключить загрузку на сайт контента с других сайтов (Например роликов ютуб)

Tags: php, сервер, vps, vds

Привет. Есть сайт, на нем полно видео роликов которые подтягиваются с ютуб.
Как отключить их подтягивание. Сделать так чтобы ролики счетчики и все прочее которое не относится к самому сайту не подтягивалось. Можно это сделать при помощи `.htaccess`

Comment: Можно в CSP (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) запретить

Comment: А зачем вы добавляете на свой сайт подобный контент, а затем пытаетесь сделать так, чтобы он не подгружался?

Comment: @terron, это обучающие видео ролики собраны на одном сайте. Временами виснет VDS методом полного отключения внешных источников хочу проверить работу сервера в момент зависания.